# Is there a way to detect what is modifying Active Directory user properties?

Tags: active-directory, logging

We use a display name format of first initial and surname, e.g. J Smith.
Recently, something is changing this to show their full name.
Is there any way to look through some logs to find out which software is writing this to AD and modifying display names?

It's only affecting some users but we can't see a pattern.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, because the logs won't know that. AD has an independant API (LDAP) and providing the name of a software that accesses it is not part of that API. As in - the AD server does not know.